# how to fix ambiguous warnings on Tesseract OCR in Swift 4/ Xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I followed [Brian Advents' tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTQ1z_8KXZo&t=3s&index=8&list=PL-AHLlRPOlZj6OJ5jfWslJhLXD3t15hbO) on how to install Tesseract OCR in my Apps.

In the tutorial he doesn't seem to have any problem, but in the latest version of Xcode I've got this couple of warning messages on build time:

[image]